# Copy text from Word with with only specific formatting

Tags: text, microsoft-word, formatting

I have text in Word which has a lot of various formatting - leading, scaling, a few sizes, and some parts are italic and some part are regular. All I need is just to copy it as plain text *but* from all the formatting the italic must stay — so I need to remove all formatting from the text except for the italics.

Is there any way to do that? I can use any software: Word, InDesign or whatever you advise.

Comment: There's no way to just retain italics. You can make a copy of everything (if you want to keep the original), then change all other parts (e.g. change the color to the same, change the size, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

First create a custom character style in Word (Let's call it "*MyItalic*"). Then use Word's Search/Replace feature to look for text in italic and apply MyItalic style to it.

Finally, import or paste in InDesign. Make sure preferences are set to import styles. Get rid of all paragraph and character styles except *MyItalic* and clear all overrides. Adjust *MyItalic* style in InDesign in order to get rid of all unwanted specifications (font and so on), just keep italics.

Of course, bold + italic, underline + italic, and so on will all be replaced by only italic.

[image]